# How can I display the result of a sqlcommand query which contains a lot of number of data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

How can I display the result of a sqlcommand query which contains a lot of number of data?
Thanks you for helping me

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please add some more details to your question and what have you tried so far?

Comment: @HR_700 Can you be more specific? And please let me know the exact environment you need.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this question is really down to a matter of opinion, and of the use case you want to implement. What do you mean by "a lot" of data? Dozens of rows? Thousands? Millions? The first step is not really a programming issue, but a user experience task.

Do you want to show the user one page of information at a time, and give them navigation buttons to switch pages? Look up **pagination**: show just a few rows, add a page index to your request properties. Here is a nice introduction to pagination: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Do you want infinite scroll, where the user can scroll down more and more, and have new chunks of data appear as they go? The solution is similar to pagination on the server side, but you will need more involved JavaScript code on the client-side.

Do you want to group data in manageable categories and let the user dig deeper hierarchically? Then you would need to rethink the entire query structure and really plan for depth.

So I'm sorry to not even try to provide any code solution, because this is not a code problem. At least not yet.